# Pass $form and $form_state as arguments in hook_menu

Tags: forms, routes

I have a javascript code below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "?q=myid_print/update_table",                                      
}).done(function(o) {
    console.log(o);               
});
```

It calls a function declared in my hook_menu:

```
function myid_print_menu()
{  
    $items = array();       
    $items['myid_print/update_table'] = array(
        'title' => 'ID History',
        'page callback' => 'myid_print_all_submitted_id_callback',                      
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;
}
```

Below is the function being invoked:

```
function myid_print_all_submitted_id_callback($form, &$form_state){  
    watchdog('myid_print', 'Wow');
    return $form['table']; 
}
```

After looking at my drupal's database, particularly in `watchdog` table, I saw the message `Wow`, which indicates that the function `myid_print_all_submitted_id_callback` has been called but my `$form_table` is not updated. The obvious reason behind this is I did not pass an argument `$form` and `$form_state`. Then, this is what my question is. How will I pass `$form` and `$form_state` arguments? Or any way that I could render `$form_table` invoke by javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Drupal's form API, it already has support for AJAX built into to it via the [#ajax property](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax). For example....

```
function MYMODULE_example_form() {
  //@TODO: various form elments...

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => '_MYMODULE_example_form_submit'
    )
  );
  return $form;
}

function _MYMODULE_example_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  //@TODO: process submitted form
}
```

The examples module [has more examples](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/ajax_example/ajax_example.module?h=7.x-1.x) of this if you'd like to see more of it in action.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, you've always been a great help.